# What should be the thickness of machine tool bed?

Tags: machine-design, machine-elements

I am developing Five-in-One machine tool which I did as a project working during 1984-85 in our Polytechnic college.  Even though we made prototype at that time, now I want to make prototype for production version.  It can be a cubical size of 1-1/2 to 2 meters.

Comment: Depends on length, material and design of internal supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the most important parameter that will affect the thickness are the vibrational performance of the machine bed, which in turn depends on :

- rpms of the motors
- feed rates
- load
- support of the bed
- etc.

Probably you need to make it thick enough to be:
a) rigid
b) with a large mass.